# Would it be possible to embed the lambda calculus in TeX?

Tags: macros, programming

I understand that TeX is Turing-complete. I'm just curious: would it be possible to embed [the lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) in TeX using TeX macros to fulfill beta-reduction?

Comment: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/lambda-lists#lambda.sty

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I spy an answer there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There exists a lambda.sty on CTAN: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/lambda-lists#lambda.sty

Comment: Perhaps a better link http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lambda-lists?